# Unable to access downloaded music from Big data downloder

Tags: 8.0, apps

I used an app to download a MP3 file from internet, i am able to play the file from within the app however am unable to access or play the file from Xbox music app.

Windows phone 8
Nokia lumia 720
Application : [Big file downloader](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/big-file-downloader/9726b00c-4365-4db1-a900-70a9c0f41e18)

I tried connecting the phone to PC and access the data still it doesn't show up anywhere in the memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Big File Downloader** is a Windows Phone 7 app, which means it will also run on Windows Phone 8. The problems is that WP7 apps cannot save songs/tracks to the Music+Videos hub, but WP8 apps can.

Also, when an app saves data like a photo, video or song - it cannot be seen by other apps or if you connect your phone to a PC or Mac. Basically, there is no way to get at the song unless there is some sort of **export** option via email, SkyDrive, Dropbox, etc.

You could contact the developer and ask for an update the app to include such features or provided a native WP8 version, which would alleviate the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Each application gets its own private data store - you would need the application to support saving/exporting to the music library - there is no general purpose file system visible between applications other than the built in libraries.

At the time of writing, "Integration with central Audio/Video hub" is listed as a future enhancement, so it may come later.

Comment: it is the property of the application there are a lot of others in which you can download your music but can't move them anywhere else or access from PC also not possible.Same problem in youtubeHD app.